# React, why is event.target.value selectively null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a very weird bug that I can't figure out.

```
  onSizeChange(e) {
    // const newSize = 24;
    const newSize = e.target.value;
    console.log('onSizeChange', newSize);
    // IsValid makes sure the value is an even number
    const isValid = newSize % 2 === 0 && newSize > 0;
    console.log(isValid);

    const newMatrix = Array(newSize).fill().map(() => Array(newSize).fill(0));
    console.log(newMatrix);
```

When I log newSize I get what I expect. i.e. 8. And when I log isValid I get true when I should. But when I log newMatrix the output is as if newSize is null no matter what newSize is. The issue isn't with Array(newSize).fill().map(() => Array(newSize).fill(0)); since it works fine when I uncomment the first line and comment the second line.

```
<div className="Buttons">
            <label>
              Board Size (Even Numbers Only)
              <input type="number" name="inputBoardSize" onChange={(e) => this.onSizeChange(e)} />
            </label>
          </div>
```

Jsx for reference

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Does it work if you used onKeyPress instead of onChange?

Comment: Also, when I tested it, newMatrix always returns an array of [{0:0}] no matter what the value of newSize is.

Comment: Adding parseInt(e.target.value) fixed it. Still don't understand the bug but hey it works

Comment: `input type="number"` actually doesn't return a number, it's still a string. Maybe that's part of the issue.